# ajax code is not navigating me to url in background

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use ajax to navigate to a php script in the background so that it performs some commands but the problem is that it is not performing the commands, which tells me that my ajax is either incorrect or I am incorrectly doing something that it is not calling the ajax. Can yo please look at the code and state what I am doing wrong? I known the php script is suppose to navigate to `insertQuestion.php` does work because if I navigate to that page using the form action, then it performs the commands in that script, but when I try and use ajax to navigate to the script in the background, it just doesn't do it:

Code:

```
<form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return myClickHandler()">

....

</form>
```

```
 function myClickHandler()
    {
        if (!validation())
            return false;

        if (!confirm("Make sure that your details are correct, once you proceed after this stage you would not be able to go back and change any details towards Questions, Options and Answers for your Assessment." + "\n" + "\n" + "Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n" ))
            return false;

        $.ajax({
            url: "insertQuestion.php",
            data: $("#QandA").serialize(),
            async: false
        });

        return true;
    }
```

UPDATE:

It is still not navigating to the insertQuestion.php page, also the problem now is that it is not checking for validation and not displaying confirm box in javascript function. Below I have included an update on what current code now looks like:

```
<form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($action); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return myClickHandler(); return false;">

....

</form>

         <script type="text/javascript">

    function myClickHandler()
    {
        if (!validation())
            return false;

        if (!confirm("Make sure that your details are correct, once you proceed after this stage you would not be able to go back and change any details towards Questions, Options and Answers for your Assessment." + "\n" + "\n" + "Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n" ))
            return false;

       $.ajax({
            url: "insertQuestion.php",
            data: $("#QandA").serialize(),
            async: false
            type: "POST"
        });

        return true;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: whey you used the return true  ?

Comment: It's a bit hard to help you debug any PHP code when you **neglect to post any of it**.  We also have no idea what is wrong with your JavaScript, as you haven't posted any useful information or surrounding code.

Comment: set your event handler not to click() but to submit()

Comment: @Brad Sorry I shouldn't of included the PHP tag, I dont know why I included it. it is not a PHP question. Sorry

Comment: @NullPointer Am I not suppose to use return true? Can I ask when I should and not should use return true?

Comment: @eicto I have set it as onsubmit() in the form tag, is that what you meant?

Comment: @NullPointer Is it because I am calling a return in the onsubmit() that I do not need to call return true in the javascript code?

Comment: yes to `submit()` and `return false;` to prevent submitting form by default browser action, as you use jquery, it is better to use something like `$('#QandA').submit(myClickHandler);`

Comment: @eicto Can you show me in your answer on how this should be written. I am just trying it another way and see if I can get it to work in the mean time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use type: "POST" because

> type String Default: 'GET' The type of request to make ("POST" or
>   "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as
>   PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by
>   all browsers.

[.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
            url: "insertQuestion.php",
            data: $("#QandA").serialize(),
            async: false,
            type: "POST"
        });
```

about submit :
HTML:

```
<form id="QandA">
...
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
myClickHandler=function(e)
    {
        if (!validation())
            return false;

        if (!confirm("Make sure that your details are correct, once you proceed after this stage you would not be able to go back and change any details towards Questions, Options and Answers for your Assessment." + "\n" + "\n" + "Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n" ))
            return false;

        $.ajax({
            url: "insertQuestion.php",
            data: $("#QandA").serialize(),
            async: false,
            type: "POST"
        });

        return true;
    };



$('#QandA').submit(myClickHandler);



});
```

Answer (score -1):

Please remove htmlentities()

```
<form id="QandA" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return myClickHandler()">

....

</form>
```

Or try another way by add "return false;" to onsubmit.

```
<form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return myClickHandler(); return false;">

....

</form>
```

Comment: Why!?  They absolutely need to be there.

Comment: because ajax used to make request, nothing referred to `action` attribute

Comment: Please add "return false;" to onsubmit then.